# R train randomForest, prox=TRUE causing failure

Tags: r, random-forest

I am training a model using randomForest. The data has been scrubbed and reduced to the bare minimum because I kept getting the dreaded
"something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing" error message.

For hours I assumed there were sparse values in factor levels or something and so I categorized (combined levels), etc.

Finally, after all this reduction, it would still fail with the error message. Just for grins, I removed the prox=TRUE parameter from the train function. All of the sudden, I'm not getting the error message. Does anybody have any insight on exactly what this parameter is doing and why it would be causing the error?

Here are some code fragments:

```
library(caret)
set.seed(121)
inTrain = createDataPartition(y = reducedData$loan_status, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)
training = reducedData[ inTrain,]
testing = reducedData[-inTrain,]

fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5, allowParallel = TRUE)

modelFit <- train(loan_status ~ ., data = training, method = "rf", trControl = fitControl)
```

Now, if I add back prox=TRUE in the train function arguments, it will cause the dreaded error message again. As long as that param isn't there, it runs.

```
Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:
    Accuracy       Kappa    
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :3     NA's   :3
```

Comment: can you provide a sample data

Comment: Yes, where would I upload it to? The reduced set is 9 MB

Answer (score 1):

Try not to use "cv" in method. Try to use others like "loocv" (leave one out cv). Usually when you have too many groups with a small number of sample in each group, then you'll have this problem and when we do CV, there is high probability that the CV cannot cover all the groups (in each train/test split). Thus it will return NA.

```
fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5, allowParallel = TRUE)
```